# Making sense of NOR get output

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-design, computers

[image]

I've been trying to figure out the various logic gates and am currently looking at a NOR gate as in the picture above. After reading various sites, I still don't get how this works as far is the output is concerned.

Based on this picture and what I know, A and B being what they are in the pic... A goes through the pMOS which gives an 1 since A is 0, and B goes through another pMOS which gives a  0 since B is 1... so you've got a 1 and a 0 going to the out put from that side, then on the other the nMOSs just take A and B and give what they are, so you have another 1 and 0 going to the out put from that end... What I don't see is how that translates to 0 for the output. I understand the meaning of NOR, that it's only true, 1, if both A and B are zero but I don't understand what's going on has far as the results of each input going through the MOSFETs to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two **PMOS**'s are active, (namely if they work) Vdd (Logic 1) could reach to Output. In case of any of them doesn't work or both of them don't work we will see Logic 0 in the Output.

**PMOS** works if you apply negative voltage (Logic 0) to gate terminal. So If you apply negative voltage (Logic 0) to both PMOS, you will see Logic 1 in the Output.

Answer (score 4):

> ... 1 ... 0 ...

You're thinking of it incorrectly.

CMOS transistors can be either open or closed, which *do not* translate to 0 and 1. If there is a closed *path* to Vss then the *output of the gate* is 0. If there is a closed path to Vdd then the output of the gate is 1. If there is no closed path to either than the output of the gate is high-impedance.